# Image to be shown on one tap on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation

I took a photo of my bus timetable, and I want to have that image as an "application" on my iPhone's home screen.

Is there an app that, when clicked, goes directly to this one image? Is there another way?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? You want an app that when launched, displays only a certain photo, correct?

Comment: [Seems like this question was asked 6 years ago.](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/homescreen-link-to-a-picture.1046878/)

Comment: Well, an app in my mind is overkill. I am thinking of my phone "desktop" (I'm not sure what it is otherwise called) and simply want to have the image there to be clicked. I don't want to have to search for it among other photos/documents. A bit like a webpage shortcut.

Comment: @ZachGates That's a good tip. So far, it seems the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better way to do this, but this should work.

Upload the image to [imgur.com](http://imgur.com). Then get the direct link to the image (it will look something like `http://i.imgur.com/ipB4C6r.png`). Open that url in Safari on your phone, hit the Share button at the bottom of the screen (the box with the arrow pointing up) and hit "Add to Home Screen."

Comment: Ok, that's a good idea, although that does need one to be online.

Comment: Since the picture is on the phone, can one not link to the local copy?

Comment: No, you can only create icons for webpages.

Comment: You may not need to be online if Safari caches the picture. I'm not sure how long it will stay cached, though

Comment: I came to my laptop to type this same answer... @jamdel beat me :]  Also leave the tab open in safari and you won't have to be online.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the photo in the stock Photos app, as long as you don't close it with the App Switcher you'll be able to the Photos app and see your bus timetable whenever you want to.

Comment: What about the 1000 other photos that are already there, and new photos to come? Won't I at some point need to scroll through and find this one photo?

Comment: As long as you don't close Photos, it will always display the photo you were last viewing, no matter how many photos you have or how many you will take, just don't close it with the App Switcher (you can run another app, but just keep Photos running in the background).

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. But this isn't really what I want since it depends on other non-actions.

Comment: It's not perfect, but how many times do you go through your photos everyday? You could probably find a 3rd-party photo viewer on the App Store, though.